# Sotah and her return to her husband

Tags: sotah-secluded-woman

With regard to the sotah, we know from the gemara that if she has not committed the sin she gets a bracha and she returns to her husband....

What kind of relationship are we trying to recreate? A husband has strong suspicion about his wife, eidim came along saying that she was secluded, and now we are trying to recreate the bond. This seems difficult in the context of trust and ahava ve'ahva -  the major pillars of Jewish relationships.

A normal husband would have strong feelings about the event, and a normal wife would be angry that she was wrongly accused and taken this degrading road.

Comment: While I get the points in your question, the Torah never says anything about anger, only about "kin'ah" - "jealousy". Since this has been removed by the wife having passed the "test", the husband has the main responsibility to improve the relationship, as his initial suspicion has been unfounded. In short, the Torah is trying to create an improved relationship, I believe. In reality, perhaps, the wife can also find a way to forgive her husband. People make mistakes. Either way, the Torah is not addressing relationship or marriage issues outside the problems of the Sotah rules, itself.